# RxJava - .doAfterSubscribe()?

Tags: rx-java

`.doOnSubscribe()` is executed *before* an observable’s subscriber is attached.

I need to execute a side effect *after* the subscriber is attached. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use composition of flows to perform something before the "real work":

```
Observable source = ... // the actual flow

source.startWith(
    Observable.empty()
    .doOnCompleted(() -> { /* your initial side-effect here */ })
)
.subscribe(/* consume the events of source */);
```

Comment: note - `.concatWith()` didn't work, but `.mergeWith()` did. Thanks! My use case is that the source is a `Relay` and the side effect mutates it. "did not work" means subscriber did not receive emission from the relay as a result of the side effect

Comment: Ah, I thought `startWith`.

Comment: @ZakTaccardi I look into this a bit. The reason I ` startWith` and `concatWith` don't work is that `startWith` is `concat` as well.So it will delay your suscription after your side effects done. But you need to do something after your downstream already set up. `mergeWith()` solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Operator doOnSubscribe is executed on subscription. It can't be said that doOnSubscribe is run before subscription or after subscription.

Comment: > is executed onSubscription

right. I'm subscribing to a `PublishSubject`, and I want to kick of a side effect that will call `publishSubject.onNext()` and the subscriber to receive the emission...