# How can I create a BehaviorSubject that subscribes to an observable?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, reactivex

I have a function which should return a `BehaviorSubject`. The subject is meant to return the most current version of a `Profile`

(user)`Profile` is just a POJO that contains references to three members:
- a `User`,
- that User's `MeasurementList`,
- and a `Deadline`.

Two of these properties is obtained via a retrofit call, and one of them is already held in a class variable.

Whenever the observable emits a new `measurement list` or `deadline`, the BehaviorSubject should emit a new updated Profile.

Here is a (hopefully helpful) diagram of what should be happening
[image]

This is what I have so far

```
 public BehaviorSubject<Profile> observeProfile() {

        if (profileBS == null) {

            profileBS = BehaviorSubject.create();

            Observable o = Observable.combineLatest(
                    Observable.just(userAccount),
                    observeMeasurements(),
                    observeDeadline(),
                    Profile::new
            );


            profileBS.subscribeTo(o); //subscribeTo does not exist, but this is what I am trying to figure out how to do.

        }
        return profileBS;
    }
```

Can anyone help me to create this BehaviorSubject properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Subject` implements the `Observer` interface so you can do the following

```
public BehaviorSubject<Profile> observeProfile() {

        if (profileBS == null) {

            profileBS = BehaviorSubject.create();

            Observable o = Observable.combineLatest(
                    Observable.just(userAccount),
                    observeMeasurements(),
                    observeDeadline(),
                    Profile::new
            );

            // Note the following returns a subscription. If you want to prevent leaks you need some way of unsubscribing.
            o.subscribe(profileBS); 

        }
        return profileBS;
}
```

Note that you should come up with a way of handling the resulting subscription.

Comment: Thanks. The answer is simple, but seemed bit counter-intuitive to me initially.

Comment: @Stephen this answer will work but with some condition. As I said in my answer you subscribe to your upstream too early. So your downstream will lose events from it.

Comment: @PhoenixWang I was in the midst of reading your answer right now. I will take a look. I actually have to head to work right now, but will follow up later. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Note that in RxJava2, `subscribe(Observer)` does not return a subscription (`Disposable`). "Unlike the `Observable` of version 1.x, `subscribe(Observer)` does not allow external cancellation of a subscription and the `Observer` instance is expected to expose such capability."

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm facing the same problem with you. I want to tell some history before I put my answer.
So I think lots of people saw the talk that JakeWharton give at Devoxx: [The State of Managing State with RxJava](http://jakewharton.com/the-state-of-managing-state-with-rxjava/)

So He came up with an Architecture which based on some transformers. But the thing is that even those Transformer instance survive outside of your ViewObservables. They still create new Observable everytime your ViewObservable using them. It's because of the concept of operator.

So a common solution for this is that using subject as a gateway as you did in your question. But the new problem is you subscribe your source too early.

The subscribe action should be done in `subscribeActual()` which will triggered by the `subscribe()` method by your downstream. But you subscribe to your upstream in the middle. You lose your events.
I was struggle a lot by fixing this problem but never find a solution.

But recently thanks to Davik's answer: [RxJava - .doAfterSubscribe()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836438/rxjava-doaftersubscribe)
I came up with something like this:

```
public BehaviorSubject<Profile> observeProfile() {
    public Observable resultObservable;
    if (profileBS == null) {

        profileBS = BehaviorSubject.create();
        //this source observable should save as a field as well 
        o = Observable.combineLatest(
                Observable.just(userAccount),
                observeMeasurements(),
                observeDeadline(),
                Profile::new
        );
        //return this observable instead of your subject
        resultObservable = profileBS.mergeWith(
            Observable.empty()
                      .doOnComplete(() -> {
                          o.subscribe(profileBS);
                      }))
    } return resultObservable;
}
```

The trick is that. You using this approche to make a operator like `doAfterSubscribe`. So only the downstream already subscribe to your subject. your subject will subscribe to your original upstream source.

Hope this can help. And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: `susbcribeActual` is rxJava2 only I think.

Comment: @JohnWowUs yes but the concept is the same. Obseravble should be considered initialize lazily by triggering `subscribe()` method. But inside this method Subject subscribe to the original source so it will receiving event from the source regardless your "main" subscribe subscribe to your Subject or not. That's why you lose events.